# Creating separate columns with binary data

Tags: r, variables, binary

Very new to R.  I have a data frame (group) that uses 1,0 for control and intervention. I would like to split the data frame and create two new variables, one with 0 (control as label) and one with 1 (intervention as label).

See below data set

```
'data.frame':   401 obs. of  14 variables:
 $ id           : int  100 101 104 105 108 112 113 114 126 130 
 $ age          : int  47 52 32 53 56 45 45 49 47 46 
 $ sex          : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
 $ migraine     : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
 $ chronicity   : int  35 8 14 10 40 27 30 49 42 3 
 $ acupuncturist: int  12 12 12 9 9 9 9 9 5 7 
 $ practice_id  : int  35 35 35 25 25 25 25 25 28 15 
 $ group        : int  1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1
```

I am looking to mutate data$group into 2 new variables, by creating a new variable control and new variable intervention and assigning 0 to control group and 1 to intervention group

Thanks

Attempted below:

```
data$control <- (ifelse(data$group == 0, "control", "intervention"))
```

This applies the categorical label to the binary numerical data point, renaming each 1 or 0 as intervention/control, which is not what i intended.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @sds5149. Lots of people will be willing to help you, but you'll need to provide data sufficient to create a reproducible example. See guide at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 0):

With base R:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(group = c(0, 0, 1))
df2 <- df1 |> 
  transform(
    control = (group == 0) * 1,
    intervention = (group == 1) * 1
  )
#   group control intervention
# 1     0       1            0
# 2     0       1            0
# 3     1       0            1
```